# SSH in to EB instance launched in VPC with NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have Launched an Elastic Beanstalk application in a VPC with Amazon RDS (postgresql) using NAT Gateway (because I want to route my application traffic through a fix public ip address) following these instructions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

**How can I ssh into the instance from my local system ?**
eb ssh is showing following error however my instance is available and not terminating.

> ERROR: This instance does not have a Public IP address. This is possibly because the instance is terminating.

**How can I login to the postgresql client ?**
Following command is not prompting anything:

> psql --host= --port=5432 --username= --password --dbname=ebdb

I know they are in private subnet so can't be accessed from public network but I want to know the possibility of that. Please help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to have a server with a public IP (in a public VPC subnet) that you can connect to from outside your VPC. I recommend setting up a t2.nano server as a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host).

Comment: Hey Mark, can you elaborate on the process here? I am new to setting up EB within a VPC and am struggling to SSH into my EB instances. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use VPN, you can also modify `sshops.py` to use the private DNS name.  Varies by OS and version, but mine is located here:

`~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/operations/sshops.py`

Search for `PublicIpAddress` (mine is on line 88), and change it to read:

`ip = instance['PrivateDnsName'] #was PublicIpAddress`

It's too bad that the EB CLI isn't on Github...otherwise I'd contribute a way to do this via a parameter.

I also added a convenient alias for this:

`alias appname='eb init appname;eb ssh --region=us-east-1 appname -n'`

This allows running `appname 1` or `appname n`, where n is the number of hosts in your cluster.